# Kotlin - extend Interface with extension function, why not working?

Tags: android, kotlin, interface, extension-methods, lazycolumn

I'm trying to understand what is happening inside of the `LazyColumn` with the interface `LazyListScope` and its extension function `items(List<T>,...)`.

The concept was new to me and I was playing around a little bit with the program.

Now, I wonder - why is this code not printing the message from the extension function?

If I'm right the method `printInterface()` is implementing `MyInterface` via an anonymous object. The extension function of the interface should work now, or not?
But if I run the program I don't see the message `"Hello"` from the extension function.

```kotlin
fun main(args: Array<String>){
    printInterface {
        printExtension()
    }
}

fun printInterface(content: MyInterface.() -> Unit) {}

interface MyInterface {}

fun MyInterface.printExtension() {
    println("Hello")
}
```

Comment: Your `printInterface` method does not invoke provided lambda?

Answer (score 1):

You need to have an instance and call it to trigger the `print`

```kotlin
fun main() {
    printInterface {
        printExtension()
    }
}

fun printInterface(content: MyInterface.() -> Unit){
    content(MyClass())
}

interface MyInterface
class MyClass : MyInterface

fun MyInterface.printExtension() {
    println("Hello")
}
```

Comment: Hey thank you for the answer. But i still dont understand. If i call printInterface() in main it shows, this:MyInterface, so an object of MyInterface was already anonymously created by the compiler. Why should the param content need an implementation of MyInterface in a class? Somehow i dont get it. Why can i not just write content()? If i look at Jetpack Compose there is no LazyListScope implemented anywhere... and the content of the items() extension function from the LazyListScope-Interface is never used in the method body?!

Comment: How would the compiler know how to implement `MyInterface`? It could be just any arbitrary interface. In the above case the compiler converts the provided lambda into a function that acts on `MyInterface`. It doesn't provide the implementation of `MyInterface` itself. Usually, `printInterface()` has to provide such implementation.

Comment: @steeveKA1 You can read more about lambda with receivers [here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/lambdas.html#function-literals-with-receiver), they've explained it pretty good there. Also, check their example for `html` function.

Comment: The `LazyListScope` is built with a combination of extension functions and lambda with receivers (inline functions as well). That's why it feels like there is no instantiation involved. As you may see they have implementation for `LazyListScope` - `LazyListScopeImpl`.